# Issue at calling another component div Id to another component

Tags: angular

Lets say I have two component: "UserPatientsReportFormComponent" and "UserPatientsReportFormTemplateComponent". I want to call "UserPatientsReportFormTemplateComponent" temaplate  id to "UserPatientsReportFormComponent".
I'll share the code below and please let me know the changes I needed to achieve it. Currently i got an error that says Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pdfData').

This below template code is from "UserPatientsReportFormTemplateComponent" component

```
<div id="pdfData" #pdfData>
    <table  *ngFor="let hubxReport of hubxReportList; let i=index">
      <tr>
        <th>{{hubxReport.categoryName}} + "Test"</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>{{column}}</th>
      </tr>
      <tr *ngFor="let item of hubxReport.hubxDataItems">
        <td></td>
        <td>{{item.itemTitle}}</td>
        <td>{{item.itemValue}}</td>
        <td>{{item.itemUnit}}</td>
        <td>{{item.normalRange}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

And this below code is for "UserPatientsReportFormTemplateComponent" component

```
export class UserPatientsReportFormTemplateComponent implements OnInit {

  clientId : number;
  hubxReportList : Array<HubxDataModel> = [];

  @ViewChild('pdfData') public pdfData: ElementRef;

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,private usersService: UsersService,private commonService:CommonService) { 

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      this.clientId = params.id == undefined ? null : this.commonService.encryptValue(params.id, false);
    });
    this.getHubxReport();
  }

  getHubxReport() {
    debugger
    this.usersService.getHubxReport(this.clientId).subscribe((response: ResponseModel) => {
      if (response != null && response.data != null && response.data.length > 0) {
        this.hubxReportList = response.data;
      }
    }
    );
  }

}
```

And from this below component im trying to access the UserPatientsReportFormTemplateComponent template div Id

```
export class UserPatientsReportFormComponent implements OnInit {
@ViewChild(UserPatientsReportFormTemplateComponent) userPatientReportFormTemplate: UserPatientsReportFormTemplateComponent; 
}
```

and I'm trying to access the template Id in this below function

```
 downloadPDF(isSubmit:any) {  
        debugger      
        let doc = new jsPDF();
        let rows: Array<any> = [];
        let header: Array<any> = [];
        let medicineInfo: any;
        let physicianInfo: any;
        let content= this.userPatientReportFormTemplate.pdfData.nativeElement; //---Error comes here---
let _elementHandlers =  
{  
  '#editor':function(element,renderer){  
    return true;  
  }  
};  
        doc.fromHTML(content.innerHTML,15,15,{  
      
                'width':190,  
                'elementHandlers':_elementHandlers  
              });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Visibility scope of @ViewChild template queries**

This means that queries done using @ViewChild can only see elements inside the template of the component itself. It's important to realize that @ViewChild cannot be used to inject:

Anything inside the templates of its child components
and neither anything in the template of parent components as well

Please refer https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-viewchild/ for more details.

You can find ways to communicate between components in here to solve your problem
https://www.thirdrocktechkno.com/blog/how-angular-components-communicate/